# Location authorization with Mapkit keeps throwing this error: (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode 9.1 Swift 4

This is the error I get in console:
[Common] _BSMachError: port 6507; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"

I'm trying to get my map to show user location in simulator (custom location) and center and zoom on that location.  I have implemented

Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description

Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

Privacy - Location Always Usage Description

in info.plist all with String values.

Here is the code in my MapVC viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    let regionRadius: Double = 1000

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self

        configureLocationServices()
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true


    }


}

extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func centerMapOnUserLocation() {
        guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, regionRadius * 2.0, regionRadius * 2.0)
        mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    }

}

extension MapVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func configureLocationServices() {
        if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        } else {
            return
        }


        }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        centerMapOnUserLocation()


    }
}
```

Upon running the app the "Access Location" popup appears and I select "Always Allow" or "Only While Using the App".  The popup disappears and the upon checking in the simulator's Privacy settings it reflects my selection.  However nothing happens after that.  I suspect that the guard let coordinate is not returning any coordinates so it's "else {return} is being called and stopping there perhaps?  Now here's the interesting part.  If I go into Settings/Privacy and select the other allow option available, when i go back into the app it performs the centerMapOnUserLocation exactly as I would like it too.

I've tried most every applicable suggestion I could find on SO as well as other sites. Nothing seems to work.  I've tried rebuilding the app from scratch 3 times all with the same results.  I just now updated to Xcode 9.2 with the same problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!!  Any additional information needed just let me know and i'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

My complete answer in **Xcode 9.1** and **Swift 4**

First add MapView on your ViewController and **connect the delegate** & check the **User Location** **checkmark** in storyboard and add MapView outlet to your ViewController.swift file. Add one Button with actionMethod called **getCurrentLocationAction()** to fetch the current location in your ViewController.swift file. Update your ViewController.swift file as below.

Also don't forget to add the two important keys in your info.plist file.

1.Privacy - Location Always Usage Description.
2.Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    fileprivate var annotation: MKAnnotation!
    fileprivate var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    fileprivate var isCurrentLocation: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.mapType = .standard

    }

    @IBAction func getCurrentLocationAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
            if locationManager == nil {
                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            }
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

}
```

Now create one extension and add the CLLocationManagerDelegate method.

```
extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        if self.mapView.annotations.count != 0 {
            annotation = self.mapView.annotations[0]
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }

        let pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pointAnnotation.coordinate = location!.coordinate
        pointAnnotation.title = ""
        mapView.addAnnotation(pointAnnotation)
    }

}
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)